# Swift: SearchBar for browser

Tags: swift, web, browser, searchbar

I'm new to Swift. I want to create a simple browser that behaves similar to Safari.

My problem is I can't search just a single word instead of typing two words in searchBar using Google.
So what is wrong?

Here's my code:

```
 func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    SearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    
    if let url = URL (string: "https://\(SearchBar.text!)") {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    } else if let url = URL (string: "https://www.\(SearchBar.text!)") {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    } else {
        let textComponent = SearchBar.text!.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + textComponent!)
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.load(urlRequest)
    }
}
```

| 1 word | 2 words | Link |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |

I'm sorry for broken English.